# SQL : First condition in OR statement in JOIN is always executed first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements

In SQL Server, I've the following design:

[image]

Is it 100% sure that the first condition from the OR statement in a JOIN will be executed first ? So that the following SQL statement will result in the green result?

```
SELECT P.Name, D.Percentage
FROM Personnel P
JOIN Department D ON
  P.Dep_Code = D.Code AND
  (P.SubDep_Code = D.SubCode OR D.SubCode = '*')
```

Comment: That will strongly depend on your database. Powerful databases such as Oracle, DB2, SQL Server will optimise (considering indexes, histograms, constraints, etc). What database is this about?

Comment: It's SQL Server (updated question)

Comment: `a or b` and `b or a` means the same in ternary boolean logic. Why would you like the join to filter out `P-A | 100` since the join condition is true for the subjacent rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it 100% sure that the first condition from the OR statement in a
> JOIN will be executed first ?

No. There is no guaranteed order of evaluation and even if there where the entire expression would still evaluate to the same value and would not influence what rows are matched in the join.

Your query will give this result:

```
Name       Percentage
---------- -----------
P-A        100
P-A        20
P-A        80
P-B        100
```

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
select P.Name,
       coalesce(D1.Percentage, D2.Percentage) as Percentage
from Personnel as P
  left outer join Department as D1
    on P.Dep_Code = D1.Code and
       P.SubDep_Code = D1.SubCode
  left outer join Department as D2
    on P.Dep_Code = D2.Code and
       D2.SubCode = '*'
where coalesce(D1.Percentage, D2.Percentage) is not null
```

You can try the queries here using SQL Server 2008. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/118492/

Answer (score 1):

Mikael's answer is correct, but this amended version of the query is more concise:

```
SELECT P.Name, D.Percentage
FROM Personnel P
JOIN Department D 
ON P.Dep_Code = D.Code AND COALESCE(P.SubDep_Code,'*') = D.SubCode
```